# Ubuntustudio Ardour VITAL synth

Tags: ardour

Help ! . . .anyone familiar with VITAL & Ardour on Ubuntustudio ? Although VITAL works fine on Bitwig & Reaper (UBUNTU) it appears in the list of plugins on Ardour but will not open up . A scan produces this info;
"INFO]: VST Blacklist:/usr/lib/vst/Vital.so"

"LV2: Failed to instantiate plugin [http://vital.audio/"](http://vital.audio/%22)

Vital does appear
in the LV2 , VST & VST3 folders under user/lib/

/usr/lib/lv2/Vital.lv2/Vital.so
/usr/lib/vst/Vital.so
/usr/lib/vst3/Vital.vst3/Contents/x86_64-linux/Vital.
so all of those files above are present in their proper folders.
Something to note is that with like HELM for example is listed in Ardour as Helm (LV2) & also Helm (VST) but Vital is just listed as Vital with no (LV2) or (VST) suffix *

Also to note is that each time the computer is started it is necessary to "sign in" to Vital on Reaper or Bitwig before it works.

Answer (score 0):

I only get vital work as vst3 version in Ardour. lv2 - just freezes Ardour permanently trying to add to mixer stack...

Ubuntu 20.04